# TraceId in not getting pushed in logs when using micrometer

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-sleuth, spring-micrometer, micrometer-tracing

I am working on a demo project to enable distributed tracing on logs.
I initially started with sleuth, but later on figured out that it is being migrated to micrometer(Sleuth is not compatible with spring boot 3.x)

But out of my surprise I am not able to see traceId and spanId in logs in my console.

Changes I have done.

**Added dependency in pom.xml**

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
        <artifactId>micrometer-tracing-bridge-brave</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>io.zipkin.brave</groupId>
                    <artifactId>brave</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

*Excluded io.zipkin.brave as it was causing a dependency conflict.*

**Added a consoleAppender on logback.xml**

```
 <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
+        <encoder>
+            <Pattern>
+                %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} [%X{X-B3-TraceId},%X{X-B3-SpanId}] - %msg%n
+            </Pattern>
+        </encoder>
+    </appender>
```

I have created a test controller:

```
@GetMapping("/log/test")
  public ResponseEntity<String> test()
  {

    log.info("Inside test");
    return ResponseEntity.ok("Done");
  }
```

When I am trying to hit this controller I am not getting traceId in logs.
sample log:

```
2023-06-20 18:19:31.649 [http-nio-8090-exec-2] INFO  a.b.c.TestController [,] - Inside test
```

As per my understanding mdc puts the traceId and spanId directly in log lines.
I am confused what I am missing here.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Change `%X{X-B3-TraceId},%X{X-B3-SpanId}` to `%X{traceId},%X{spanId}`

Comment: I had tried that already but it is not working, giving same result

Comment: Here you have working examples https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer-samples

Comment: Can you be more specifc about it , as  I have opened it it seems it is using traceId to attach in logs, But that is not the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `Hooks.enableAutomaticContextPropagation()` to the `main()` function fix this issue for me